# A computer program can become stalled or staled?

Tags: adjectives

What's the correct expression:
"This software is stal**l**ed!"
or
"This software is staled!"

Comment: A dictionary will provide you with the meanings of 'stall' and 'stale'.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen or heard either of those words being used in that context.

"This software has stalled" - would mean that the program had stopped responding.
"This software has become stale" - could mean that the program has become boring or perhaps has now been superceded by a later version.